# PhoneGap Build media.play() Takes A Long Time To Start Playing

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, phonegap-build

I'm working on a PhoneGap app for iOS that lets you listen to MP3s and watch MP4s.

Normally, I would just use `<a href="file.mp3">file.mp3</a>` or `<video src="file.mp3"></video>` to play the file and let the system media player handle things.  This time, it was requested that the audio continue to play when the screen is off.  The default handling is to fade out and pause the media, when the screen is locked.  The [PhoneGap API Documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_media_media.md.html#media.play) gives some sample code that includes the [playAudioWhenScreenIsLocked](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_media_media.md.html#media.play_ios_quirks) option.  That code seems to be working, in that the MP3s continue playing when the screen is locked.

The problem that I'm having is that it takes a considerable amount of time for said file to start playing.  For instance, a 27MB MP3 file took 1 minute 50 seconds to start playing on an iPhone 4s (3g) and 2 minutes on an iPad 2 (WiFi).  It took seconds to download that same file, on my desktop.  It almost seems like it's having to download the entire file before it starts playing.  That doesn't seem like it should be necessary.  To compliment that theory, if I try to play an MP4 (using `media.play()`), it takes even longer and then closes the app.

config.xml (identifiable parts replaced with xxx):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- config.xml reference: https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml -->
<widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" id = "org.xxx.xxxbeta" version = "2.0">
    <name>xxx Beta</name>
    <description>xxx Live   ///   Design update</description>
    <author href="http://www.xxx.org" email="xxx@xxx.org">xxx</author>
    <!-- Enable individual API permissions by defining each here.  The 'device' permission is required for the 'deviceready' event. -->
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />

    <!-- Customize your app and platform with the preference element. -->
    <!-- If you do not want any permissions to be added to your app, add the following tag to your config.xml; you will still have the INTERNET permission on your app, which PhoneGap requires. -->
    <preference name="permissions" value="none"/>
    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="2.9.0" /> <!-- all: current version of PhoneGap -->
    <preference name="orientation" value="default" /> <!-- all: default means both landscape and portrait are enabled -->
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal" /> <!-- all: possible values handset, tablet, or universal -->
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="false" /> <!-- all: hides the status bar at the top of the screen -->
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" /> <!-- ios: control whether the screen 'bounces' when scrolled beyond the top -->
    <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="false" /> <!-- ios: if icon is prerendered, iOS will not apply it's gloss to the app's icon on the user's home screen -->
    <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" /> <!-- ios: external links should open in the default browser, 'true' would use the webview the app lives in -->
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" /> <!-- ios: black-translucent will appear black because the PhoneGap webview doesn't go beneath the status bar -->
    <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" /> <!-- ios: controls whether data types (such as phone no. and dates) are automatically turned into links by the system -->
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" /> <!-- ios: if set to true, app will terminate when home button is pressed -->
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="false" /> <!-- ios: if set to false, the spinner won't appear on the splash screen during app loading -->
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" /> <!-- ios: if set to false, the splash screen must be hidden using a JavaScript API -->
    <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" /> <!-- blackberry: prevents a mouse-icon/cursor from being displayed on the app -->
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" /> <!-- android: MIN SDK version supported on the target device. MAX version is blank by default. -->
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" /> <!-- android: app install location. 'auto' will choose. 'internalOnly' is device memory. 'preferExternal' is SDCard. -->

    <!-- Plugins can also be added here.  A list of available plugins are available at https://build.phonegap.com/docs/plugins-->
    <!--<gap:plugin name="GAPlugin" />-->

    <!-- Define app icon for each platform. -->
    <icon src="images/logo.png" />
    <icon src="images/Icons/icon-57.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57" />
    <icon src="images/Icons/icon-72.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72" />
    <icon src="images/Icons/icon-114.png" gap:platform="ios" width="114" height="114" />
    <icon src="images/Icons/icon-144.png" gap:platform="ios" width="144" height="144" />

    <!-- Define app splash screen for each platform. -->
    <gap:splash src="images/LaunchScreens/launch-iphone-app-P.png" gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="480" />
    <gap:splash src="images/LaunchScreens/launch-iphone-app-P-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="960" />
    <gap:splash src="images/LaunchScreens/launch-iphone-5-app-P.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136" />
    <gap:splash src="images/LaunchScreens/launch-ipad-app-P.png" gap:platform="ios" width="768" height="1024" />
    <gap:splash src="images/LaunchScreens/launch-ipad-app-P-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1536" height="2048" />
    <gap:splash src="images/LaunchScreens/launch-ipad-app-L.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1024" height="768" />
    <gap:splash src="images/LaunchScreens/launch-ipad-app-L-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="2048" height="1536" />

    <!-- Define access to external domains. -->
    <!-- 
    <access /> - A blank access tag denies access to all external resources.
    <access origin="*" /> - A wildcard access tag allows access to all external resource.
    <access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/> - allow local pages only
    <access origin="http://phonegap.com" /> - allow any secure requests to http://phonegap.com/
    <access origin="http://xxx.org" subdomains="true" /> - same as above, but including subdomains, such as http://build.phonegap.com/
    <access origin="http://xxx.org" browserOnly="true" /> - only allows http://phonegap.com to be opened by the child browser.
    -->
</widget>
```

HTML (identifiable parts replaced with xxx):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Featured Series | xxx Live</title>
    <!-- required for the redirectToSystemBrowser() function -->
    <script src="phonegap.js"></script>
    <!-- used to change the formats of dates -->
    <script src="date.js"></script>
    <!-- jquery (we might as well use it) -->
    <script src="jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- our javascripts -->
    <script src="xxxlive.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="featuredseries">
    <header>
        <h1><a href="index.html"><abbr title="xxx">xxx</abbr> <span>Live</span></a></h1>
    </header>
    <section id="content">
    </section>
    <!-- page specific javascripts -->
    <script>
        // load the featured series content
        seriesDownload(featuredseries);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript (identifiable parts replaced with xxx):

```
// phonegap api media playing
function playAudio(url) {
    // Play the audio file at url
    var my_media = new Media(url,
        // success callback
        function () {
            console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
        },
        // error callback
        function (err) {
            console.log("playAudio():Audio Error: " + err);
        }
    );
    // Play audio even if the screen is off
    my_media.play({ playAudioWhenScreenIsLocked : true });
}

// generic get JSON data function
function fetchJSONFile(path, callback) {
    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
            if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
                var data = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);
                if (callback) callback(data);
            }
        }
    };
    // false tells it to be synchronous instead of asynchronous
    httpRequest.open('GET', path, false);
    httpRequest.send(); 
}

// get a bunch of series information from a json api
function seriesDownload(seriestitle) {
    var series, number, description;
    // tell the function where the JSON data is
    fetchJSONFile('http://www.xxx.org/api/seriesdownload/?series=' + seriestitle, function(data) {
        // do something with your data
        // alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        // alert(data.title + ', ' + data.camelcase);
        series = data.series;
        number = data.seriesnumber;
        description = data.description;
        $('#content').append('<h2>' + series + '</h2>');
        $('#content').append('<blockquote><p>' + description + '</p></blockquote>');
        for (var i = 0, l = data.sermons.length; i < l; i++) {
            var date, speaker, seriespart, sermon, sermonpart, sermonsubtitle, sermonsubtitlepart, mp3, mp4;
            //alert(data.events[i].name);
            date = data.sermons[i].date;
            // date.js doesn't seem to like the iso8601 time zone offset
            var date_readable = Date.parse(date.substring(0, 19)).toString('dddd, MMMM d, yyyy');
            speaker = data.sermons[i].speaker;
            seriespart = data.sermons[i].seriespart;
            sermon = data.sermons[i].sermon;
            // replace non-alphanumeric characters with nothing
            var sermon_camelcase = sermon.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/g, '');
            sermonpart = data.sermons[i].sermonpart;
            sermonsubtitle = data.sermons[i].sermonsubtitle;
            sermonsubtitlepart = data.sermons[i].sermonsubtitlepart;
            mp3 = data.sermons[i].downloadlinks.mp3;
            mp4 = data.sermons[i].downloadlinks.mp4;
            $('#content').append('<h3>Pt. ' + seriespart + ' - ' + sermon + '</h3>');
            $('#content').append('<dl id="' + sermon_camelcase + '">');
            $('#content #' + sermon_camelcase).append('<dt>Date Preached</dt>');
            $('#content #' + sermon_camelcase).append('<dd><time datetime="' + date + '">' + date_readable + '</time></dd>');
            $('#content #' + sermon_camelcase).append('<dt>Speaker</dt>');
            $('#content #' + sermon_camelcase).append('<dd>' + speaker + '</dd>');
            $('#content #' + sermon_camelcase).append('<dt>Download Links</dt>');
            $('#content #' + sermon_camelcase).append('<dd id="' + sermon_camelcase + '-downloadlinks">');
            $('#content #' + sermon_camelcase + ' #' + sermon_camelcase + '-downloadlinks').append('<ul>');
            $('#content #' + sermon_camelcase + ' #' + sermon_camelcase + '-downloadlinks ul').append('<li class="link" onclick="playAudio(\'' + mp3 + '\')">Audio (MP3)</li>');
            $('#content #' + sermon_camelcase + ' #' + sermon_camelcase + '-downloadlinks ul').append('<li class="link" onclick="playAudio(\'' + mp4 + '\')">Video (MP4)</li>');
            $('#content #' + sermon_camelcase + ' #' + sermon_camelcase + '-downloadlinks').append('</ul>');
            $('#content #' + sermon_camelcase).append('</dd>');
            $('#content').append('</dl>');
        }
    });
}
```

So, basically, the page calls a JavaScript function that calls a JSON API and turns that data into a bunch of text.  That text contains links to the function that plays the audio (nothing, particularly, crazy).

Is there something, obvious, that I'm doing incorrectly or does the PhoneGap Media API actually just take that long to operate?  I wouldn't think so, or people would be in an uproar about it.  I haven't read other reports of people having similar problems.

Unfortunately, I can't really test this on my desktop as my browser doesn't have access to all the [PhoneGap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/) stuff (I figured it was worth noting Build as there are some differences).

It may also be worth noting that I tried including the [Media plugin](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/229) by adding `<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" />` to my config.xml.  When I updated the app, it gave me this error (`Unable to create app: plugin unsupported: org.apache.cordova.media`).  That code is what they recommend on their website.  config.xml uses `<gap:plugin name="GAPlugin" />`, so I tried `<gap:plugin name="Media" />` as well.  I got a similar error (`Unable to create app: plugin unsupported: media`).

I've not worked with PhoneGap plugins, before, so it could be that the lack of plugin is what is causing the long pause before playing.  I wouldn't think so, given that this should be built-in core functionality of the API.